# Use YUI 2's Rich Text Editor for Inline Editing

Tags: javascript, yui, rich-text-editor, inline-editing, yui-datatable

I am using inline editing in YUI 2's DataTable. I would like to use the Rich Text Editor for this, but it is not among the built-in options. Does anyone know of code that does this or how one might go about integrating it?

Answer (score 0):

The rich text editor just requires a textarea with an Id, so make your own custom implementation of a yui datatable column editor, and define the appropriate text area within it.